# Book with mentally controlled space mechas fighting

Tags: story-identification, novel, robots

I read a book a few years ago, but can only remember specific bits and pieces of it now. The main character was the pilot of a warrior mentally controlled robot mecha thing, which could travel the galaxy using a network of portals. The enemies had the ability to read their minds, so the robot had a self destruct system, which could be activated by layers and layers of mental switches followed by a physical one.

Could anybody help me find this novel?